# Where can I see these LogCleaner stats?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have download the source code of Apache Kafka and I have seen that there are some stats that are printed somewhere. Where can I find these information about the log cleaner threads? I don't see it in the logs.

Here are the stats in the LogCleaner.scala file:

```
  val message =
    "%n\tLog cleaner thread %d cleaned log %s (dirty section = [%d, %d])%n".format(id, name, from, to) +
    "\t%,.1f MB of log processed in %,.1f seconds (%,.1f MB/sec).%n".format(mb(stats.bytesRead),
                                                                            stats.elapsedSecs,
                                                                            mb(stats.bytesRead/stats.elapsedSecs)) +
    "\tIndexed %,.1f MB in %.1f seconds (%,.1f Mb/sec, %.1f%% of total time)%n".format(mb(stats.mapBytesRead),
                                                                                       stats.elapsedIndexSecs,
                                                                                       mb(stats.mapBytesRead)/stats.elapsedIndexSecs,
                                                                                       100 * stats.elapsedIndexSecs/stats.elapsedSecs) +
    "\tBuffer utilization: %.1f%%%n".format(100 * stats.bufferUtilization) +
    "\tCleaned %,.1f MB in %.1f seconds (%,.1f Mb/sec, %.1f%% of total time)%n".format(mb(stats.bytesRead),
                                                                                       stats.elapsedSecs - stats.elapsedIndexSecs,
                                                                                       mb(stats.bytesRead)/(stats.elapsedSecs - stats.elapsedIndexSecs), 100 * (stats.elapsedSecs - stats.elapsedIndexSecs).toDouble/stats.elapsedSecs) +
    "\tStart size: %,.1f MB (%,d messages)%n".format(mb(stats.bytesRead), stats.messagesRead) +
    "\tEnd size: %,.1f MB (%,d messages)%n".format(mb(stats.bytesWritten), stats.messagesWritten) +
    "\t%.1f%% size reduction (%.1f%% fewer messages)%n".format(100.0 * (1.0 - stats.bytesWritten.toDouble/stats.bytesRead),
                                                               100.0 * (1.0 - stats.messagesWritten.toDouble/stats.messagesRead))
  info(message)
```

Comment: You mean you want the raw stats variable here instead of needing to parse the log output? Or you're not seeing these log lines at all? What login file are you looking at? What are your current log4j properties?

Comment: I don't see these log lines in the kafka logs. Where can I see these lines? The file is LogCleaner.scala. I am using the default log4j.properties file but with these lines:
log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=DEBUG, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=true

Comment: By default, you should see those logs in `log-cleaner.log` file. And the default log4j has additivity as false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @OneCricketeer pointed out - the specific logs you are looking for are in the log-cleaner.log files. Here is an example of entries there:

```
[2021-06-08 07:45:24,132] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning segment 6692959 in log __consumer_offsets-29 (largest timestamp Tue Jun 08 07:45:13 EDT 2021) into 6692959, retaining deletes. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2021-06-08 07:45:24,717] INFO Cleaner 0: Swapping in cleaned segment LogSegment(baseOffset=6692959, size=3331) for segment(s) List(LogSegment(baseOffset=6692959, size=104856549)) in log Log(/apps/kafka-data/__consumer_offsets-29) (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2021-06-08 07:45:24,717] INFO [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]:
 Log cleaner thread 0 cleaned log __consumer_offsets-29 (dirty section = [6692959, 6692959])
 100.0 MB of log processed in 1.3 seconds (76.6 MB/sec).
 Indexed 100.0 MB in 0.7 seconds (144.7 Mb/sec, 53.0% of total time)
 Buffer utilization: 0.0%
 Cleaned 100.0 MB in 0.6 seconds (162.9 Mb/sec, 47.0% of total time)
 Start size: 100.0 MB (944,401 messages)
 End size: 0.0 MB (31 messages)
 100.0% size reduction (100.0% fewer messages)
 (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
```

Also, in addition to those logs, if you are interested in all log cleaning info, I found log entries like below, in the main server.log, very useful too - they show when log segments are marked for deletion and why:

```
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,828] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Found deletable segments with base offsets [11760980] due to retention time 2592000000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,833] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2] Writing producer snapshot at offset 11762941 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,835] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Rolled new log segment at offset 11762941 in 7 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,835] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Scheduling log segment [baseOffset 11760980, size 1079204] for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
```